# .Net framework 4.7.1 missing from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frameworks

I'm starting to make some games with Unity (c#). The problem is that when I open a script in Visual Studio 2017, it shows me an error that says .net framework 4.7.1 is missing on my machine. I tried to install it but Visual Studio shows me the same error. I don't know how to fix it.
Here it is a screenshot of my problem, it's in Spanish, but actually says that I haven't got .net Framework 4.7.1

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y39BI.png)

Comment: Start the visual studio installer, click on modify, select the individual components tab, select .net framework 4.7.1 SDK and targetting pack. install.

Comment: Alternatively, update to unity 2018.3 or later and use the .net standard 2.0 compatibility level.

Comment: I found the solution! I had to select .net framework 4.7.1 on the visual studio installer and it doesn't give me the error anymore. Thanks!

Comment: Saved me a lot of time. Thanks!.